# How to do indoor directions on an Android Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-indoor-maps

I am doing an app that allows users to get directions from one room to the next room of the same building and require the application to show the user indoor directions. I have tried and tested the Google Maps Intent which opened the Google Maps app and gave directions from one room to the next. I am required to not allow the user to open up an external map app and then receive directions. Instead they must use the Google Map built into my application. I was wondering if it's at all possible to do indoor directions on Google Maps Android API. Would genuinely appreciate any help I get. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps Android API v2 has options for indoor maps. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/ under 'Indoor Maps' for a quick example.

Of course, that doesn't prevent them from using an external app by itself, but it does let you provide them indoor map data in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the main intention is to give indoor directions from one room to the next. I currently have the directions going from one side of the building to the other but these directions are on the outside of the building. So its one external point of the building with a direction to another external point of the building. The intention is to have a route from one internal part of the building to the other internal point of the building. Do you have any knowledge on this?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you should have to start by using internal sensors to navigate.  Add an indoor map of the building so that you would know where you are at in the building.